# How to normalise 110.110 in floating point binary?

Tags: math, floating-point, binary, normalization, fixed-point

I'm working on a task for A-Level Comp Sci and one question involves normalising the number 110.110 in floating point representation with a 6 bit mantissa and a 4 bit exponent. What is the correct way to do this?

I can't move the decimal point to the beginning of the mantissa (0.110110) as that would cause it to exceed 6 bits but I also can't move the decimal point to the first 1 (1.10110) because then it would act as a negative sign bit. Do I just leave it as is with no exponent or is there something I'm missing? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IEEE-754 normalized numbers mantissa always lies in range `1.0..2.0`, in binary `1.0000000 ... 1.1111111`. Bit before point is always set, so it is omitted, and we store only part of mantissa after point.

In your case `110.110 = 100 * 1.10110`, so mantissa is `10110` (or `101100` if 6 bits needed)

Exponent `100` perhaps is stored as `100 + 111 = 1011` (by analogy with single precision exponent stored as `e+127`).

Sign bit in IEEE-754 float values is separate leftmost bit. Don't sure about your format

So I suppose the next binary code:

```
0 1011 101100
s eeee mmmmmm
```

Comment: @Alex Carr Note I corrected mistake with exponent

Comment: Details: IEEE-754 uses _significand_ and not _mantissa_.

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica Indeed subtle difference exists, while definition says `The significand[1] (also mantissa[2] or coefficient,[1] sometimes also argument, or ambiguously fraction`